# How to join collection by nested object field in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, join, collections, aggregate

1. I have an example item from collection 'users':

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612e8361942c250f4ca280f3"),
    "_cart" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "60e38a2f2f6338e00e4ceff6",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "60e38a2f2f6338e00e4ceff7",
            "count" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "60e38a2f2f6338e00e4ceff8",
            "count" : 4
        }
    ],
    "name" : "max1",
    "email" : "andrey.kupets1@i.ua"
}
```

2. I have products collection like:

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60e38a2f2f6338e00e4ceff6"),
    "name" : "Куб-лабиринт Svoora Замок",
    "category" : "Настольные игры",
    "price" : 449.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60e38a2f2f6338e00e4ceff7"),
    "name" : "Настольная игра Hasbro Классическая Монополия обновленная (C1009_121)",
    "category" : "Настольные игры",
    "price" : 449.0
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60e38a2f2f6338e00e4ceff8"),
    "name" : "Настольный футбол Merchant Ambassador 2-в-1",
    "category" : "Настольные игры",
    "price" : 1899.0
}
```

3. How to join a product-object to `_cart`-field in user-collection by nested `_id`-field in `_cart`-field?
4. I try to join in this way:

```js
db.getCollection('users').aggregate([
    {$lookup: {
        from: 'products',
        localField: '_cart',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: '_productsInCart'
    }}
])
```

5. I expect next output:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("612e890a3bb5da0328c4ffe4"),
    "_cart" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "60e38a2f2f6338e00e4ceff6",
            "count" : 2
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "60e38a2f2f6338e00e4ceff7",
            "count" : 3
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "60e38a2f2f6338e00e4ceff8",
            "count" : 4
        }
    ],
    "name" : "max1",
    "email" : "andrey.kupets1@i.ua",
    "_productsInCart" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60e38a2f2f6338e00e4ceff6"),
            "name" : "Куб-лабиринт Svoora Замок",
            "category" : "Настольные игры",
            "count" : 2,    
            "price" : 449.0,
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60e38a2f2f6338e00e4ceff7"),
            "name" : "Настольная игра Hasbro Классическая Монополия обновленная (C1009_121)",
            "category" : "Настольные игры",
            "count" : 3,
            "price" : 449.0,
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("60e38a2f2f6338e00e4ceff8"),
            "name" : "Настольный футбол Merchant Ambassador 2-в-1",
            "category" : "Настольные игры",
            "count" : 4,
            "price" : 1899.0,
        }
    ]
}
```

6. But actually i have output in _productsInCart field:

```js
"_productsInCart" : [ ]
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use below aggregation: pls refer to https://mongoplayground.net/p/FfWpFZKdxhV

```
db.users.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$_cart"
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "_cartObjId": {
        "$toObjectId": "$_cart._id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "products",
      localField: "_cartObjId",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "_productsInCart"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$_productsInCart"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "_cart": {
        "$push": "$_cart"
      },
      "_productsInCart": {
        "$push": "$_productsInCart"
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```